# Can I change where win7 shortcuts sort in relation to folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, sorting

If i have a group of folders, and somehow i need a shortcut to a folder to be "in the middle" sequentially, how do i fix that? 
Changing sort by type does not help, sorting by name does not seem to change the situation even though strictly by name it would make sense.

[image: picture of problem]

Comment: I highly doubt there is a solution to this, but its a good question regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Workaround A - Shortcuts only

1. Create a new folder.
2. Cut the `item2.lnk` shortcut, and paste it into the new folder.
3. Create shortcuts pointing to the `item1` and `item3` folders.

### End result

[image: shortcut]

---

## Workaround B - Junction points / symbolic links

1. Delete the `item2.lnk` shortcut.
2. Open a command prompt window, and type the following to navigate to the folder:

   ```
   cd /d "X:\Path\to\the\main\folder"
   ```
3. Create a [junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) targeting the `item2` folder:

   ```
   mklink /j "item2" "X:\Full\path\to\item2\folder"
   ```

### End result

[image: junction point]

### Known limitations

- You can't create junction points targeting remote shares. In such cases you have to create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) instead. Symbolic links were introduced with Windows Vista, but are also available in Windows XP through third party filter drivers. For Vista and later, the syntax is the following:

  ```
  mklink /d "symbolic link" "X:\path\to\target\folder"
  ```

  **Note** Per default system settings, only users in the Administrators group can create symbolic links.
- Junction points and symbolic links are only supported on NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder that contains item1 and item3, create a new folder called item2. Then drag the shortcut item2 into the new folder item2. You are left with three folders (item1, item2, and item3) in proper alphabetical order. The folder item2 has only one thing in it: the shortcut to (the real) item2. 
     This is very simple, although I do grant you that it takes two steps rather than one to open the real item2.